# 2 Combination and Permutation Questions : 1. a ) 10 coins flipped and arranged in a row. How many possible arrangements contain exactly two heads?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

1. a) $10$ coins are flipped and arranged in a row. How many possible 
     arrangements contain exactly two heads?
    
   b) How many arrangements contain at least two heads?

Question 2. a) Two $6$ sided dice are rolled. How many possible ways are there for them both to roll even?(As in get two even numbers)

My answer for 1a) $10!/2!$ 1b) $10!/2! + 10!/3! + 10!/4! + \ldots + 10!/10!$

My answer for 2b) $$\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$$ 
- basically the combination formula: $$\frac{N!}{(N-r)!r!}$$

Are my answers correct? If not, what are the correct answers?
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are not correct. A good check of this is to consider the size of the number of arrangements you have for 1a and 1b and the number of possible combinations of even die rolls you have. There are 36 different combinations for 2 die, but you say there are $C(6,3)^2 = 400$ ways for both the die to be even.

1a) Consider the following chart. We will fix one placement of H and allow the other placement of H in the arrangement to vary. Notice, that as we move down the rows, we must exclude 1 possible arrangement as not to double count.

\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7& 8 & 9 & 10& \text{Arrangements}\\
H &  &  &  &  &  & &  &  & &9 \\
 & H &  &  &  &  & &  &  & &8\\
 &  &H  &  &  &  & &  &  & &7\\
 &  &  &H  &  &  & &  &  & &6\\
 &  &  &  &H  &  & &  &  & &5\\
 &  &  &  &  &H  & &  &  & &4\\
&  &  &  &  &  &H &  &  & &3\\
&  &  &  &  &  & &H  &  & &2\\
&  &  &  &  &  & &  &H  & &1\\
&  &  &  &  &  & &  &  &H &0\\
\end{array}
Add up these possible arrangements for each placement of H, and we have 45 i.e $C(10,2)$.

1b) To find the amount with at least 2 heads it to find the complement of at most 1 head. The number of arrangements with 0 heads is 1. The number of arrangements with 1 head is 10. The total number of arrangements is $2^{10}$. So, the number of arrangements with at least 2 heads is $2^{10} - (1 + 10) =  1013$.

2) A good demonstration of this is to fix one of the die with an even number, and vary the second entry.

\begin{array}{cccc}
(2,\_):& (2,2)&(2,4)&(2,6)\\
(4,\_):& (4,2)&(4,4)&(4,6)\\
(6,\_):& (6,2)&(6,4)&(6,6)\\
\end{array}
As you can see, there are only 9 ways for this to happen.